# GitLab Auto Deployment

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, digital-ocean, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I have 2 Web servers connect by a load balancer on Digital ocean and a git-lab server.
When one of the local branches pushes the code to the Git-lab server, i want the  git-lab server to automatically push the code to 2 web-servers and deploy on them. 
How can I configure that ?
Should I configure CI/CD ?

Comment: using a ci would be useful, I suggest looking at gitlab web hooks.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html